# iOS incorrect segue on different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I have an app currently on the app store, and I just found the craziest bug. My main testing device is an iPhone 6 and everything works perfectly. I tested the app on the iPhone 6 Plus simulator to check sizing and spacing and it all checked out so I released it. Today I was with a customer using a 6 Plus and one of the buttons was segueing to the wrong view controller. I went back and tested it and it keeps doing it. Works great on all iPhone 6 and 6s. Goes funky on 6 Plus and 6s Plus.

I'm using a storyboard created segue dragged straight from the button to the destination view controller.

Has anyone ever run into this or heard of this? Any ideas on how I could fix it?

EDIT: Filed Apple Bug Report #27089815

Comment: Is your button by any chance inside the cell of a table view?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño It isn't

Comment: Could you add some code showing how you are implementing the segue?